# The paint appears on the other side of the object

Tags: texture-painting

https://youtu.be/hDXD-1i3DiA
Hi!
I'm a complete beginner in Blender. Yesterday I made a 3d model and wanted to create a texture for it in Substance Painter, but there is a problem, when I line it up in a certain way it seems like there is no front 'wall' (you could see the other side of it).
See the link.
There was also a similar problem when I tried to texture paint it in Blender (the paint would just appear on the opposite side of object that I was painting).
Did I make some mistake while making a model?
What could it be and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like your face normals are flipped (i.e. the inside is pointing outwards) and backface culling is enabled (i.e. making the backside of a face invisible). To correct this, select the object and go into Edit Mode by pressing Tab, then select all with A, then recalculate normals by pressing Ctrl+N.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped